# I am trying to do this question but, state is giving me problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs

You have a GroceryApp component, which receives a list of products, each one with name and votes. The app should render an unordered list, with a list item for each product. Products can be upvoted or downvoted.

By appropriately using React state and props, implement the upvote/downvote logic. Keep the state in the topmost component, while the Product component should accept props.

```
const Product = props => {
  const {name,votes} = props.product
      
  const plus = () => {
    // Call props.onVote to increase the vote count for this product
    props.onVote(1,props.index);
  };
  const minus = () => {
    // Call props.onVote to decrease the vote count for this product
    props.onVote(-1,props.index);
  };
  return (
    <li>
      <span>{name}</span> - <span>votes: {votes}</span>
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>{" "}
      <button onClick={minus}>-</button>
    </li>
  );
};

const GroceryApp = (props) => {
  var [products, setProducts] = React.useState(props.products);
      
  const onVote = (dir, index) => {};
      
  return (
    <ul>
      {products.map((product,index) => (
         <Product product={product} index={index} onVote={onVote} />
      ))}
      {/* Render an array of products, which should call onVote when + or - is clicked */}
    </ul>
  );
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";

ReactDOM.render(
  <GroceryApp
    products={[
      { name: "Oranges", votes: 0 },
      { name: "Bananas", votes: 0 }
    ]}
  />, document.getElementById('root')
);


let plusButton = document.querySelector("ul > li > button");
if (plusButton) {
  plusButton.click();
}
console.log(document.getElementById('root').outerHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your products and sort them during rendering (can be costly if your list is very large).

```
const GroceryApp = (props) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState(props.products);
  
  const onVote = (dir, index) => {
    const nextProducts = [...products];
    const product = products[index];
    nextProducts[index] = { ...product, votes: product.votes + dir };
    setProducts(nextProducts)
  };
  
  return (
    <ul>
      {products
        .sort((a, b) => b.votes - a.votes) // descending sort
        .map((product,index) => (
          <Product product={product} index={index} onVote={onVote} />
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I cannot give you points because I don't have jejeje, but really thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import React from "react";

const Product = (props) => {
const plus = (ind) => {
    props.onVote("+", ind);
    // console.log({ ind });
};
const minus = (ind) => {
    props.onVote("-", ind);
    // console.log({ ind });
};
return (
    <li>
    <span>{props.product.name}</span> -{" "}
    <span>votes: {props.product.votes}</span>
    <button onClick={() => plus(props.index)}>+</button>{" "}
    <button onClick={() => minus(props.index)}>-</button>
    </li>
);
};

const GroceryApp = () => {
let [products, setProducts] = React.useState([
    { name: "Oranges", votes: 0 },
    { name: "Bananas", votes: 0 },
]);
const onVote = (dir, index) => {
    const Products = [...products];
    if (dir === "+") {
    Products[index].votes = Products[index].votes + 1;
    setProducts(Products);
    } else {
    Products[index].votes = Products[index].votes - 1;
    setProducts(Products);
    }
};

return (
    <ul>
    {products.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} onVote={onVote} index={index} product={product} />
    ))}
    </ul>
);
};
export default GroceryApp;
```